# How do I fetch some data from external API in react JS?

Tags: reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      let posts;
      if(json.userId > 16 ){
        return console.log();
      }
});
```

I'm trying to fetch 15 data from external API which has like 100 data, here's the code I'm currently writing but when I run it, it won't show any data

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on the right track with using the `fetch` function to retrieve data from an external API. However, I noticed a few issues with your code that may be causing it to not display any data.

First, in your `fetch` call, you're only checking the response from the API in the `then` block. However, you need to also handle any errors that may occur. You can do this by adding a `.catch` block at the end of the `then` block.

Second, in your `json` response, you're only checking if the `userId` is greater than 16, but you're not actually doing anything with the data. To display the data, you need to set it to the component state or render it directly in your component's `render` method.

Here's an example code snippet that fetches the first 15 posts from the JSONPlaceholder API and stores them in the component state:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=0&_limit=15";
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ posts: data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error: error });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { posts, error } = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <ul>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, we're using the `fetch` function to retrieve the first 15 posts from the API by adding `_start=0` and `_limit=15` query parameters to the URL. We're also handling any errors that may occur using the `.catch` block.

When the data is successfully retrieved, we're storing it in the component state using `this.setState`. In the `render` method, we're mapping over the `posts` array in the state to render each post's title in an unordered list.

If an error occurs, we're displaying an error message instead of the post list.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: thank you for answering, it made me learn something new, and i found a way to slice it as well! can you please explain to me how to make it look like it has 3 columns each row? I'm kind of confused because its using the url to fetch the data, I tried to do : 
.container {
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 but it wont work